# Renaming tag [spatial] to [spatial-data-types]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag [spatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spatial) with a wiki excerpt of:

> Spatial data types store geometric data, that is data related to an
>   object's position in space.

and a wiki of:

> Spatial data types store geometric data, that is data related to an
>   object's position in space. Many popular databases engines now include
>   support of spacial data types, including:
>
> - [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) - see [Spatial Data (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx)
> - [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) - see [MySQL Spatial Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html)
> - [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) - see [Geometric Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-geometric.html)

There is a Stack Exchange devoted to spatial questions called the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) (where GIS stands for Geographic Information System).

Consequently, it appears that the topic of "spatial" is MUCH broader than has been narrowly defined here as [spatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spatial) [data types only].

Should this anomaly be addressed, and if so, how would that be best done?